# Python input returns None

Tags: python-3.x, input

When executing this code(simplified) I get None printed in the cmd, while I was expecting it to print out whatever I wrote as an answer to Foo: , and then it prints Bar. Why does this happen?

```
def contin(message):
    input(message)

answ = contin('Foo: ')
print(answ)
if answ == None:
    print('Bar')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything, so by default it returns `None` is such cases. You need to return `input(message)`:

```
def contin(message):
    return input(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def contin(message):
    return input(message)

answ = contin('Foo: ')
print(answ)
if answ == None:
    print('Bar')
```